# Dynamically load NextGen gallery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dynamic, lightbox2, nextgen-gallery

I would like to have a 'Projects' page that has 10 images on it, 1 per project. When clicking on the image I would like to then load a further 5 images into a lightbox gallery.
The snag is that I do not want to load all images for all projects on page load. Can this be done dynamically?

I am currently using Next Gen Gallery, and would like to remain doing so, however if there is an alternative way that would have to avoid using the WP plugin, I can work with that.

Here is the page in question, currently loading all images from all galleries:
http://www.customgardens.co.uk/garden-design-work-portfolio/

Comment: Here is the page in question, currently showing all images from all galleries.

Comment: Can anybody help with advice on this dynamic image loading issue? Thanks in advance!